# Text-mask addon with IE 11 + angular 7+

Tags: angular, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11, angular7, masking

I am working on a project where my collegues used a 3rd party text masking method.
[This one](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask) with [createNumberMask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/addons/#readme) addon.

I got the glorious sub-task to allow IE10+ users to view our gorgeous work.
However if we use this mask IE11 yells at me in windows saying:

```
SCRIPT1010 identifier expected @vendor.js
```

I dove into this issue and it points to a function call:

```
export default function createNumberMask(***/error points to this location/***{
  prefix = dollarSign,
  suffix = emptyString,
  includeThousandsSeparator = true,
  thousandsSeparatorSymbol = comma,
  allowDecimal = false,
  decimalSymbol = period,
  decimalLimit = 2,
  requireDecimal = false,
  allowNegative = false,
  allowLeadingZeroes = false,
  integerLimit = null
} = {}) {...
```

The imported function is used like:

```
 mask = createNumberMask({
     allowDecimal: true,
     prefix: '',
     suffix: '',
     thousandsSeparatorSymbol: ' ',
     integerLimit: 13,
   });
```

**// constructor is used after this assignment**

And said mask used in html as documentary suggests.

How could I hack this so it's working with IE11 as well?
We have no issues with other browsers but IE10+ (we don't bother with IE9).

Comment: Please try to check in which compatibility mode your site is getting load in IE. It can be possible that by default it get  load in IE 7 compatibility mode. If it is than please try to use IE 10 or later mode may help to fix this error.

Comment: I've looked into that previously it's running in version 11

Comment: Try to add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> in your HTML file to see whether it makes any difference in this issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT i've added the said meta tag as well but still it shrieks for identifier